# Very Simple URL Rewrite - Help Please

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting, windows-server-2008-r2

IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have the following (which was generated by URL rewrite 2.0):

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="?p={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
```

I thought it would cause

http://localhost/56321

to be interperated as:

http://localhost/?p=56321

Can anyone see what it wrong? It just gives a 404 error.

I have also tried a url redirect rule and that works fine so I know the module is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct but the regular expression to which you match the URL should not start with a slash. The following works:

```
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="?p={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Hope this helps.